# Object.watch doesn't catch delete - why? any workaround?

Tags: javascript, firefox

As you can see from this console experiment, Firefox [watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) works when an assignment was made, but not when element was deleted:

```
thing
[object Object]
thing.watch('b',function() {console.log(':)))') } );
undefined
thing.b = 'hi'
"hi"
":)))"
delete thing.b
true
```

Any workaround to see where a property was removed?

Comment: While you delete, value becomes undefined, so one way is to check for that
.

Comment: Yeah, but the neat thing about watch is you can immediately be notified when something changes, and console.trace() what caused it.